# $\int_W x^2y^2 = \int_V x^2y^2$. Is my proof of this equation right? ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres)

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
The following example is EXAMPLE 4 on p.149:

> **EXAMPLE 4.** Suppose we wish to integrate the same function $x^2y^2$ over the open set $$W=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<a^2\}.$$
> Here the use of polar coordinates is a bit more tricky. The polar coordinate transformation $g$ does *not* in this case define a diffeomorphism of an open set in the $(r,\theta)$ plane with $W$.  However, $g$ *does* define a diffeomorphism of the open set $U=(0,a)\times (0,2\pi)$ with the open set $$V=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<a^2\text{ and }x<0\text{   if   }y=0\}$$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. See Figure 17.5; the set $V$ consists of $W$ with the non-negative $x$-axis deleted. Because the non-negative $x$-axis has measure zero, $$\int_W x^2y^2=\int_V x^2y^2.$$ The latter can be expressed as an integral over $U$, by use of the polar coordinate transformation.

Is my proof of the following equality right?

> $\int_W x^2y^2=\int_V x^2y^2.$

> **Theorem 11.3.** Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:Q\to\mathbb{R}$; assume $f$ is integrable over $Q$.
> (a) If $f$ vanishes except on a set of measure zero, then $\int_Q f=0$.

> **Theorem 13.3 (Properties of the integral).**
> (d) (Additivity). If $S=S_1\cup S_2$ and $f$ is integrable over $S_1$ and $S_2$, then $f$ is integrable over $S$ and $S_1\cap S_2$; furthermore $$\int_S f=\int_{S_1} f+\int_{S_2} f-\int_{S_1\cap S_2} f.$$

My proof is here:

> Let $T:=\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x<a\text{ and }y=0\}$.
> Then, $W=V\cup T$ and $V\cap T=\emptyset.$
> So, by Theorem 13.3(d), $\int_W x^2y^2 = \int_V x^2y^2 + \int_T x^2y^2 - \int_{V\cap T} x^2y^2$.
> Since $T$ and $V\cap T$ have measure zero, $\int_T x^2y^2=0$ and $\int_{V\cap T} x^2y^2=0$ by Theorem 11.3.
> So, $\int_W x^2y^2 = \int_V x^2y^2$.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: @Lorago Thank you very much for your answer!